# I have an LLC taxed as an S-Corp. Can my LLC receive income on a 1099?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, form-1099, s-corporation

I have a single-member LLC taxed as an S-Corp. I'm a contractor and a lot of my clients pay on a 1099. Can I have those clients pay my LLC with that 1099, so I can consolidate my income as going to one place? It would be frustrating to have to operate as if I have two business - myself and my LLC - when they are really the same.

Also, if the 1099 has my name on it, can that still be counted as income to the LLC? Or does the name on the 1099 have to be the LLC name?

Answer (score 1):

Well... It depends on the contract. If your clients have a contract with the LLC - that's who they would pay. If they have a contract with you personally - then that's who's going to be paid.

Renegotiate the contracts through your LLC.

Comment: Thanks @littleadv, if the 1099 has my name on it, can that still be counted as income to the LLC? Or does the name on the 1099 have to be the LLC name?

Comment: @number41 it has to be the LLC's name and EIN.